# Erase part of Konvajs image

Tags: html5-canvas, konvajs

I'm trying to upload a local image to a konvajs stage and then erase parts of the image that are not needed. My upload works well and the draw/erase work but I'm unable to erase the uploaded image. I can only erase the draw line over the image.

```
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: width,
    height: height
    });
```

I have created a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tommy6s/L3f27mch/

I read two stackoverflow posts similar to mine that featured a round eraser tip but I still could not figure out how to get mine to work.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this demo I was using separate `<canvas>` element for drawing canvas.
You can draw your image directly into canvas via context:

```
img.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(img, 0,0, width/2, height / 2)
    layer.draw();
};
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L3f27mch/2/)

Comment: lavrton - Thank you for the great solution and learning experience!